# how to save state last function in case of error in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, logging

> declare  V_OUTPUT integer;
>
> begin V_OUTPUT := function1(data_rif);
>
> V_OUTPUT := function2(data_rif);
>
> V_OUTPUT := function3(data_rif);
>
> V_OUTPUT := function4(data_rif);
>
> return V_OUTPUT; end;

All functions return 0 if they are performed correctly.
So at the end the V_OUTPUT variable should be equal to 0
But if one of the functions fails, I want to know which function is wrong.
What do you recommend?
I thought to put a progressive counter and save it in a log
thank you

Comment: What happens if one of them fails? Exception? Non-zero return value? If non-zero, do each return the same on a failure? Same for any failure type or unique per type?

Comment: If one of the functions fails, the basic function which executes all the functions I have written above stops and returns an error message.
Every function on indicated if it is successful returns 0.
At present if one of the functions goes wrong, I get a message telling me that there was an error. I wanted to understand which of the functions generated it

Answer (score 0):

Either use four variables to catch the return values or just check for errors right after the call of a function and handle any errors there. Right now you overwrite the return value of a previous call right away.

```
DECLARE
    V_OUTPUT integer;
BEGIN
    V_OUTPUT := function1(data_rif);
    IF V_OUTPUT <> 0 THEN
      -- error handling for function 1
    END IF;

    V_OUTPUT := function2(data_rif);
    IF V_OUTPUT <> 0 THEN
      -- error handling for function 2
    END IF;

    V_OUTPUT := function3(data_rif);
    IF V_OUTPUT <> 0 THEN
      -- error handling for function 3
    END IF;

    V_OUTPUT := function4(data_rif);
    IF V_OUTPUT <> 0 THEN
      -- error handling for function 4
    END IF;

    return 0;
END;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the functions are sequential.
So if an intermediate function fails, it makes no sense to execute the others.
I thought about putting nested ifs, and everyone returns a progressive number that helps me understand the if that went wrong.
What do you think?

Comment: @GiovanniMandolino: Nested `IF`s are OK, some even consider them the cleaner way. But of course you can put a `RETURN ...` for the `-- error handling ...` in my code and had the same effect. Whatever you consider more readable/understandable/extendable for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that the functions are sequential.
So if an intermediate function fails, it makes no sense to execute the others.
I thought about putting nested ifs, and everyone returns a progressive number that helps me understand the if that went wrong.
What do you think?

```
 DECLARE
        V_OUTPUT integer;
    BEGIN
        V_OUTPUT := function1(data_rif);
        IF V_OUTPUT <> 0 THEN
          return 1
          ELSE
           V_OUTPUT := function2(data_rif);
           IF V_OUTPUT <> 0 THEN
              RETURN 2
             ELSE
             V_OUTPUT := function3(data_rif);
             IF V_OUTPUT <> 0 THEN
             RETURN 3
             ELSE
             V_OUTPUT := function4(data_rif);
             IF V_OUTPUT <> 0 THEN
              RETURN 4
              ELSE
              return 0;
             END IF;
            END IF;
          END IF;
        END IF;

    END;
```